# Docker - R creates multiple processes

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile

I'm creating a `docker container` and I'm installing `R` in it.

The problem is, that when running `R` in the container, the main `R` process create `ncores - 1` subprocesses.

So when running the docker on my laptop with `8 cores`, I get `1 R process` and `7 R subprocesses`.

I also tried to configure my Docker file similar to this:

> https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/eeb9c8a5f416f7cfe982734440e39fa72abbcb33/r-base/Dockerfile

but is still not working.

**Docker-file:**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN sed -e 's/archive\.ubuntu/at\.archive\.ubuntu/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install libatlas3-base
RUN apt-get -y install libopenblas-base
RUN apt-get -y install r-base
RUN apt-get -y install r-base-dev
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils

RUN echo "deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
RUN gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

Did someone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but the whole problem was caused by installing `libopenblas-base`.

After removing the line

```
RUN apt-get -y install libopenblas-base
```

everything worked fine!